# sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error - Updating Database

Tags: python, database, syntax, sqlite

got the following error when trying to update my database:

`sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error`

This is the section of code that is creating the error:

```
cursor.execute("""UPDATE SchoolRecordsTable SET Event, Year, YearGroup, Student, Gender, Result WHERE Event=? and YearGroup=? and Gender=? VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", (event_name, dateyear, year, studentname, gender, student_results, event_name, year, gender))

db.commit()
```

Any ideas as to why it's creating an error? Also, do I need "VALUES(?, ?...)" when updating a database or not? I have tried both with and without but I can't check because of the *OperationalError*.

Comment: Use it like this `UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2...., columnN = valueN
WHERE [condition];`

Comment: Just tried this method and get the error 'sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: event_name' @zetysz . Should I be puttnig column1 as "column1" or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the [correct syntax for an UPDATE statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html).

Use something like this:

```py
cursor.execute("""UPDATE SchoolRecordsTable
                  SET Event=?, Year=?, YearGroup=?, Student=?, Gender=?, Result=?
                  WHERE Event=? and YearGroup=? and Gender=?;""",
               (event_name, dateyear, year, studentname, gender, student_results,
                event_name, year, gender))
```

(Note: changing the three columns that you used to look up the row is pointless.)

Comment: I've tried this and it's worked, thanks. I have now realized that I do not need to update the columns that I use to search for after looking at what I more specifically want to change (before I wanted to update all the columns but 1). Cheers mate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this syntax `cursor.execute('update table  set a=? where id=?`, a,id)
Try this:

```
cursor.execute("""UPDATE SchoolRecordsTable SET Event=?, Year=?, YearGroup=?, Student=?, Gender=?, Result=? WHERE id=? """, (event_name, dateyear, year, studentname, gender, student_results, your_id))
```

For more help add more details.